# Access Database created from other class (Android/JAVA)

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to list items from database which is created from another class.
But I don't know how to access it without creating the object again. here's the code:

AddItemActivity:

```
public class AddItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MyDBHandler dbHandler;

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);

    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
}

public void insertButtonClick(View view) {
    Item item = new Item(...);

    dbHandler.addItems(item);
}
```

MyDBHandler:

```
Public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

...

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void addItems(Item item) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    // INSERT ITEMS
    values.put(COLUMN_ITEM, item.getName());
    ...

    db.close();
}

public String printDatabase() {
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String printQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(printQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        dbString += "Item: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEM)) +
                    " \t Amount: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_AMOUNT)) +
                    " \t Price: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRICE));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

Now I want to list all the items in another Activity but I don't know how to access the **dbHandler** which was created in **AddItemActivity**

```
public class ListItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_base);
}

public void printDatabase() {
    String dbString = ****.printDataBase();
    databaseTextView.setText(dbString);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make it static ! try to write 
`public static MyDBHandler dbHandler;`
and access it like this 
`AddItemActivity.dbHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting an instance of `MyDBHandler` in your `Application` class?

```
public MyApplication extends Application
{
    private static MyApplication mInstance;
    private MyDBHandler mDatabase;

    ...

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance()
    {
        if ( mInstance == null )
        {
            mInstance = new MyApplication();
        }

        return mInstance;
    }

    public MyDBHandler getDatabase()
    {
        return mDatabase;
    }
}
```

In your activities, use it like this:

```
public class AddItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_add_item );

        // Get database from application instance
        dbHandler = MyApplication.getInstance().getDatabase();
    }
}

public class ListItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private MyDBHandler mDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_data_base );

        // Get database from application instance
        mDb = MyApplication.getInstance().getDatabase();
    }

    public void printDatabase()
    {
        String dbString = ****.printDataBase();
        databaseTextView.setText(dbString);
    }
}
```